How have other DBAs gotten around the lack of Oracle documentation for installing Oracle 19c on Red Hat Linux 9 without using ASMLib?
For one of our applications, we are trying to stack validate running our application on RHEL9 and Oracle19c.
We currently use RHEL7 and ASMLib, but ASMLib is not currently available for RHEL9. We don't want to use RHEL8 because it will hit EOL soon.
Oracle support pointed us to use ASMFD (Filter Driver), but that only works with very specific builds of RHEL9 (which will break as soon as we patch the Operating System).
Also, all of the documentation shows how to migrate from ASMLib to ASMFD, but not how to perform a full clean installation of ASMFD.
Working solution, at the moment, is running using UDEV rules to create the disks.
